# How can a government save, if it has deficit?

Tags: macroeconomics, government-debt, saving

I am reading an IMF paper about China's debt ([link](https://www.imf.org/%7E/media/Files/Publications/WP/2018/wp18277.ashx)) which says:

*❝ Despite a large augmented fiscal deficit of 10 percent, fiscal savings remain higher than other countries, resulting from the biased composition of spending towards investment ❞*

How can a government have deficit and at the same time have positive savings?

Answer (score 4):

Government can have savings while having deficit because we are just talking about savings not *net* savings.

For example, imagine that government has zero tax revenue $\\\$10$ spending and $\\\$10$ of public investment. In this case the government is running deficit of $\\\$20$ yet it is also saving through investment. Due to the deficit being larger than saving on *net* basis government still dis-saves but saving is not zero.

So it is completely possible to save and run a deficit at the same time.

Comment: @elemolotiv no net saving is tax revenue-government spending (T-G). In this case that would be $-\$10$.

Comment: sorry I am trying to pull things together. From 
$Y=C+I+G+NX$ we can derive $(Y-C-T)+(T-G)=I+NX$. That includes $NetSavings=(T-G)$ but where does government investment go? - alternatively could you suggest a source with all the formulas? thanks!

Comment: @elemolotiv government investment is part of $I$ in some undergraduate textbooks $I=S$ but that’s simplification actually even better undergraduate textbooks will mention its $I=S+T-G$. See for example Blanchards et al macroeconomics an European perspective